# Delete Azure App Registration API Permission programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory

I need to delete the API permissions from an App registrations programmatically. I have tried below code snippet to update the application. But it is not deleting permanently. It is moving the permission from "Configured permissions" to "Other permission granted for [TENANT]

Configure Applications
https://snipboard.io/PQTR8k.jpg

Other granted permission
https://snipboard.io/r38e0y.jpg

I deleted the OBO-Service-Test-v1 -> Access_as_user permission. Then it moved to Other granted permission

```
            //Get Application 
            var result = await _graphClient.Applications[$"{objectId}"].Request().GetAsync();
           
             //Get all permissions
            var permissiontoDelete = result.RequiredResourceAccess;

            var requiredResourceAccess = new List<RequiredResourceAccess>();
          
           //Add permissions except the one to delete to list
            foreach (var item in permissiontoDelete)
            {
                if (item.ResourceAppId != proxyClientId)
                    requiredResourceAccess.Add(new RequiredResourceAccess() { ResourceAppId = item.ResourceAppId, ResourceAccess = item.ResourceAccess });
            }
            var updateApplication = new Application { RequiredResourceAccess = requiredResourceAccess };

           // Update application with all permissions except the one to delete.
           await _graphClient.Applications[$"{result.Id}"]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync();
```

How can we delete an API permission permanently from an App Registration?

Comment: If the permission has been granted, you need to remove things from the associated Service Principal. Delegated permissions = OAuth2PermissionGrants, application permissions = AppRoleAssignments

Comment: @juunas To get the associated Service Principal, we have to use below code, right?
_graphClient.ServicePrincipals[$"{objectId}"]

Comment: Yeah, if you know the object id of the service principal in advance. Otherwise you might have to make a query to the service principal list endpoint with "appId eq 'your-app-client-id'" as a filter.

Comment: @juunas When I checked MSDN, there is no delete feature for delegated permission grants https://snipboard.io/XxMlye.jpg
For AppPermissions it is there, but admin privilege is needed.

Comment: Bit difficult to find, but it is there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 1):

***Please note that, admin consent is granted for your API permissions.***

If you try to remove those permissions **`without revoking admin consent`**, they will go from *'Configured permissions'* to *'Other permission granted for Tenant_Name'* like below:

[image]

> **Please note that admin privilege is needed to revoke admin consent.**

As suggested by ***juunas*** in the comments, you can delete the permissions from associated service principal like below:

To delete **Delegated Permissions**,

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

await graphClient.Oauth2PermissionGrants["{oAuth2PermissionGrant-id}"]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync();
```

To delete **Application Permissions**,

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{servicePrincipal-id}"].AppRoleAssignments["{appRoleAssignment-id}"]
    .Request()
    .DeleteAsync();
```

If admin consent is not granted, you can delete the API permissions directly using your code where revoking admin consent is not needed.

**References:**

[Delete appRoleAssignment - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delete-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Delete oAuth2PermissionGrant (a delegated permission grant) - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)